# Network Manager Not Picking up VPN's Nameservers

Tags: 13.04, dns, vpnc

So I installed Ubuntu [13.04](/questions/tagged/13.04) (switch from Fedora) two days ago and I'm almost productive again except for one thing:

When I connect to my work's VPN, Network Manager doesn't pick up the nameservers like Fedora did.  When I connect I can ping the IP addresses directly:

```
$ ping source.my-company.com
> ping: unknown host source.my-company.com
$ ping 123.45.67.890
> 64 bytes from 123.45.67.890: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=67.8 ms
> ...
```

What's more irritating is that I can easily ping the nameservers too.  My network guy wants me to manually edit `resolv.conf`, but that's not sustainable since I regularly switch between 3 VPNs.  (Another source of irritation for another day: Fedora allowed me to connect to multiple VPNs, why won't Ubuntu?)

My question is how do I begin to debug this? I'm unfamiliar with DNS and Networking in general, and using new tools makes it harder to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your VPN connection, click **IPv4 Settings** tab, select **Automatic (VPN) addresses only** in **Method** dropdown and type your company's DNS servers and domain in the boxes at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Actually *just* figured out how to fix the problem, but this was only half of the problem.  I commented out dns=dnsmasq in the NetworkManager.conf and that fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bummer of an issue: on Fedora NetworkManager automatically found the dns servers and domains.  Is there any way to get that functionality in Ubuntu?